# Is it possible to be warned when comparing a non-null value to null in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, if-statement, null

Assuming --strictNullChecks is on.

When I create a variable and I implicitly say that it can't be null (e.g. a number) and then I compare the value of this variable to `null`, there is no warning saying "This condition will always return false" being emitted.

```js
const a: number = 5;

// I would expect this to emit a warning, because the condition will always evaluate as false
if(a === null) { 
    // do something
}

// same here, this will always evaluate as true
if(a !== null) {
    // do something else
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: In WebStorm those statements will emit warnings in the IDE stating "Can be simplified to false" and "Can be simplified to true"

Comment: That might actually be helpful, thank you

Comment: Also thought that a linting rule could capture it, but did not find one that matched this.